# Which type of binding is better to use for a huge amount of data in Telerik RadGrid?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have implemented grid on my ASPX page by using [Telerik RadGrid](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx). I work with a huge amount of data (~1 million records). I do sorting and filtering by using [header context menu](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/new-filtering-menu-for-radgrid-for-asp-net-ajax). I have noticed that the filtering usually takes too much time. I need to wait more than 5 minutes till I can apply filter to the next column. Is it a good idea to use client-side binding instead of server-side in order to boost the filtering process?

Comment: I think you need some sort of load 9m demand so you can fetch one page at a time. Client binding likely offers that but may need some difficult web service. I think there was an event like NeedDatasource that could also be useful.

Comment: @rdmptn I have a handler for `NeedDataSource` event. Here I retrieve filtered and sorted result which I use for updating `DataSource` property. I also implemented paging. I don't think I follow you. What should I do in the handler in order to speed up the filtering?

Answer (score 0):

Be it listview, gridview, or say other 3rd party controls?

They are good for aobut 500, maybe 1000 reocrds. As noted beyond say 30-40, then we can and will use a data pager. But, as noted, ALL rows are still being pulled.

But, the VERY instant you get beyond about 1000 rows? then you have to dump the built in data pagers, and adopt REAL AND TRUE sql server paging.

From sql 2012 onwards, they added some additonal paging options, and thus if  you hit a table with 1 million rows, but only are displaying 30 per page, then only 30 rows will be pulled. You quite MUCH HAVE to adopt server side paging, and as noted, anything beyond 1000 rows is WAY TOO HUGE AND LARGE to use a built in data pager (they work by pulling all rows first - you can't do that anymore).

So, that means you have to dump the built in pager, and roll your own. You need to keep track of the page number you are on, but the basic template for sql server works like this:

```
--CREATING A PAGING WITH OFFSET and FETCH clauses IN "SQL SERVER 2012"
DECLARE @PageNumber AS INT, @RowspPage AS INT
SET @PageNumber = 2
SET @RowspPage = 10 
SELECT ID_EXAMPLE, NM_EXAMPLE, DT_CREATE
FROM TB_EXAMPLE
ORDER BY ID_EXAMPLE
OFFSET ((@PageNumber - 1) * @RowspPage) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @RowspPage ROWS ONLY;
```

So, one of course probably would wrap above in a store procedure, and you pass the page number you want.

so, that way, when you hit sort, or whatever, you data operations will only occur on 30 records (or whatever page size you have), and thus you performance issues should go away.

so, built in paging kind of fakes real data paging , and as noted, that works for about max 1000 rows. Anything larger, you have to dump the built in paging methods, and roll your own based on the above concept.